# Javascript autocomplete source from div value dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, php, autocomplete

i am writing a javascript function on php file to perform autocomplete. i have to take input from a div value where it is like

```
value1
value2
...
```

The input div value is dynamic and changes on click event of some text. so every time when user click those values i call a function named `test()` which reset the autocomplete function.

I am writing following code to get value and after editing sending as source to autocomplete function.

```
Select Value: <input id="autocomplete">

<script type="text/javascript">

        function test()
 {

             var div_values = document.getElementById("id_div_values").innerHTML;
             var div_val_arr = div_values.split("</li>");
             var search_val ="[";


                  for (var j = 0; j < div_val_arr.length-1; j++)
                  {                                                      
                     search_val = search_val+"\""+div_val_arr[j].replace("<li>","")+"\"";

                   }
              search_val = search_val+"]";

            $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
               source: search_val
            });           

         }
      </script>
```

but it's not working. i have checked div value it's coming properly and forming it in array, but it's not working. if i put source as

```
source: ["value1","value2","value3","value4"];
```

then it is working perfectly. i am not getting where i am doing mistake.
Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var div_val_arr = [];
$("#id_div_values li").each(function() {
    div_val_arr.push($(this).text());
});
$('#autocomplete').on('focus click touchstart',function() {
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: div_val_arr
});
});
});
```

**html**

```
    <div id="id_div_values">
        <ul>
    <li>some value</li>
    <li>another value</li>
    <li>value3</li>
    <li>value4</li>
    <li>value5</li></ul>
    </div>

<input type="text" title="search" id="autocomplete">
```

**fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/arfrbzbz/1/

Comment: Thanks Peter! jsfiddle helped a lot and got the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

First you are missing to append ","(comma) in following code

```
search_val = search_val+"\""+div_val_arr[j].replace("<li>","")+"\"";
```

Above code will make array as following:

```
search_val =["value1""value2""value3""value4"];
```

Add comma and make sure it will genrate array as follows.

```
search_val =["value1","value2","value3","value4"];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have added "\"," in the code but it is not working.

Comment: You cant do by using above method ("\"," ) because at the end there will be a extra comma.  search_val =["value1","value2","value3","value4",];  You need to remove that comma or manage that comma.

Comment: Use first method as you were using and then replace double quotes by following way.                                          search_val = search_val+"\""+div_val_arr[j].replace("<li>","")+"\"";                      search_val=search_val.replace("\"\"","\",\"");

Comment: Thanks Sujit i have applied it but it's not working.

Comment: can you create js fiddle of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by directly assign the div_val_arr as your source for your auto complete

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
           source: div_val_arr
 });
```